# what are the npm module spport Redis Sentinel as a for session store

Tags: node.js, session, redis, redis-sentinel, express-session

I am going to use redis sentinel cluster as a session store in my Node js (express) web application. Could you please list the best npm module for do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's old and poor (like me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a redis driver. It seem working good.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis

Answer (score 1):

For sentinel Check out redis-sentinel https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-sentinel, also please read this link to get a good understanding about it http://engineering.docusign.com/articles/redis-sentinel-client-nodejs/

Comment: I can confirm the package in that blog post doesn't work. Do not use it.
I got a failover to a slave and no event was emitted. I ended with a read only slave and my application started crashing.

Comment: well thanks for telling me that, well right now which package are you using ??

Comment: just use redis cluster instead of redis sentinel and use the project endorsed by the redis project in their website.

Comment: Worked for me. I made the master go to sleep until a failover occurred and continued to receive events from a subscribed channel

Answer (score -2):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis is a good start.
It's got 4800 stars on github as well

Comment: This is not supporting for redis-sentinel

Comment: there is no support for redis-sentinel ??